# How to do a MANOVA (statistics) from within java?

Tags: java, r, statistics, stata, anova

I need to do a program that runs a MANOVA analysis. The best would be to run the analysis from within java, but if it's imposible it can call R or Stata, or some statistics software that runs a MANOVA and then exports the results to java again.

I'd like to know if you know of any library that can help me with this or if there is a way to call the statistics software from within java...

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.mhsatman.com/rcaller.php

They have an example program on how to execute R commands from java. It looks simple. Use `manova` function to  do analysis in R and get the summary.

But there are existing problems as mentioned in this blog comments - http://stdioe.blogspot.com/2011/07/rcaller-20-calling-r-from-java.html

examples: http://code.google.com/p/rcaller/source/browse/#hg%2FRCaller%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fexamples%253Fstate%253Dclosed

I would give it a try though.

Also, another project called rsession:
http://code.google.com/p/rsession/

Comment: They have examples with updated code in their google code page:- http://code.google.com/p/rcaller/ and http://code.google.com/p/rcaller/source/browse/RCaller/src/main/java/examples/